# yum: Difference between mysql, mysql-server and mysql-devel

Tags: centos, sql, yum

What are the differences between the packages here?

mysql, mysql-server and mysql-devel

I am installing a SQL server to use with PHP, but I found these three packages and am not sure which to use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll probably want all three packages.

`yum info mysql mysql-server mysql-devel` will provide maintainer-written descriptions of the packages in detail.

But in short, `mysql` is the MySQL client and necessary libraries. `mysql-server` is the actual database server, with corresponding daemon and init scripts. `mysql-devel` includes development packages that my be needed by other applications.

Comment: Just want to add a comment for the OP that `yum info <package name>` will tell you all of this.  It's a good one to know so you can get more information about any other package in the future.

Comment: mysql-devel should only be needed for building applications which use mysql. It should not be needed for applications which merely use mysql.